# IsolatedStorageFile doesn't write to file

Tags: c#, persistence, isolatedstorage

I have to store the contents of a control between sessions. This is what I do:

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile f = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly();
        using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("somefilename", FileMode.Create, f))
        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            foreach(string path in searchFoldersListView.Items)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(path);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is attached to the `Closing` event of the window. When debugging, the control goes through all the items, but when I run the program again, the control is empty. It turns out that when I navigate to the file, it's empty. When I change the code to save to a regular file by putting a `File.AppendAllText()` in the foreach loop, that file is saved just fine. Why is that?

EDIT: reading event handler:

```
    private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile f = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly();
        using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("somefilename", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, f))
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                searchFoldersListView.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually write the code to *read* the file?  Why didn't you post it?

Comment: `IsolatedStorageFile` is also `IDisposable`. Try putting it in a `using` statement as well.

Comment: @HansPassant I did not find that to be important since I verified that the file is empty by navigating to it. Added anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your method that reads from the file. You only read the first line which is probably `null`. Try the following:

```
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            searchFoldersListView.Items.Add(line);
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```